# Should I avoid use of TEXT, NTEXT datatypes?

Tags: sql-server

I'm making a blog, article website so i decide to use NTEXT data type for blog and article contents. Until i see this

> Important
>
> ntext, text, and image data types will
>   be removed in a future version of
>   MicrosoftSQL Server. Avoid using these
>   data types in new development work,
>   and plan to modify applications that
>   currently use them. Use nvarchar(max),
>   varchar(max), and varbinary(max)
>   instead.
>
> Fixed and variable-length data types
>   for storing large non-Unicode and
>   Unicode character and binary data.
>   Unicode data uses the UNICODE UCS-2
>   character set.
>   (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Im sure that blog and article contents gonna reach 4000 character limit if i use nvarchar(max).
What data type should i use at this case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nvarchar(max) vs NText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133946/nvarcharmax-vs-ntext)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use nvarchar(max)/varchar(max) - that's current pair of text types.

When using these types you have no limit for field size (well, actually the limit is 2 Gb, but I don't think you'll hit it).

See MSDN for more details:

- [data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) in SQL Server
- [nchar and nvarchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) types

Comment: Are you sure of that? I remember facing issues when using nvarchar when we reached 4k charaters.

Comment: Absolutely sure. Most likely you were using sized nvarchar field, i.e. the one with fixed max length (like nvarchar(2000)). In this case there's a limit on maximum length value and it is 4000 symbols (which is 8000 bytes which is a limit for max size of varchar fields of fixed max length).