# SQL CE Max Length

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

I need to store articles in an application for WP7. I just want to use a database so I can query by unread articles, etc, etc.

I've run into one big problem with SQL CE in Mango-- there seems to be a limit of 4000 characters, and my article is 4200. And that isn't even the biggest one.

How can I get around this limit, if at all? If not, will I have to use a different database or possibly just write stories to IsolatedStorage and manage the file references in the database?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The 4000 byte limit is imposed on `varchar` fields.

If you want more then you'll need ot use `ntext`.

See the list of supported types at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424(SQL.110).aspx

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133946/nvarcharmax-vs-ntext for issues with using ntext.

Answer (score 4):

In Sql Compact 3.5, there was an ntext data type that was not limited to 4k bytes (like nvarchar).