# SQL Server 2005: Insert query returning Operand type clash: ntext is incompatible with smallint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have what I hope is a quick question. Haven't found working code for this, and I'm at a little bit of a loss.

I'm working with an old database on SQL Server 2005. It has a dynamic questionnaire (or a thousand, actually... long story), and each question can have the answer stored as either a smallint or as ntext.

The current "answers" table is as follows:

```
AnswerID (PK, int, not null)
EvalID (int, null)
QuestionID (int, null)
NumericAnswer (smallint, null)
TextAnswer (ntext, null)
```

(Yes, I know `ntext` is deprecated. It's an old table.)

This table now has over 300,000 records in it, and is getting really large. So I'm looking for more efficient ways to store the data, and decided to do a little experiment with moving everything to a single sql_variant field (currently, each row can have data in just one of the two answer columns, not both).

So I made another table, called `AnswersTest`:

```
AnswerID (PK, int, not null)
EvalID (int, null)
QuestionID (int, null)
AnswerGiven (sql_variant, null)
```

... and I'm now trying to get all of the existing data from `Answers` to `AnswersTest`, preferably in their original order... so I'm running an insert query, and it's not working. I've tried both the following:

```
INSERT INTO AnswersTest (EvalID, QuestionID, AnswerGiven)
SELECT EvalID, QuestionID, ISNULL(NumericAnswer,TextAnswer) AS AnswerGiven FROM Answers ORDER BY AnswerID
```

...and

```
INSERT INTO AnswersTest (EvalID, QuestionID, AnswerGiven)
SELECT EvalID, QuestionID, CONVERT(ntext,CASE WHEN NumericAnswer IS NULL THEN TextAnswer ELSE NumericAnswer END) AS AnswerGiven FROM Answers ORDER BY AnswerID
```

In both cases, I get the following:
`Operand type clash: ntext is incompatible with smallint`

I know there must be a simple answer to this... I'm just drawing a blank (it's been a couple of months since I've had to do anything much with TSQL), and I can't find a working answer through searching. Please help. :)

EDIT: Found an answer through trial and error...

The answer may not have been the best one (and it may jump through some unnecessary hoops), but it's a one-time query and it works. :)

```
INSERT INTO AnswersTest (EvalID, QuestionID, AnswerGiven)
SELECT EvalID, QuestionID, CASE WHEN CONVERT(sql_variant,NumericAnswer) IS NULL THEN CONVERT(sql_variant,CONVERT(varchar(8000),TextAnswer)) ELSE CONVERT(sql_variant,NumericAnswer) END AS AnswerGiven FROM Answers ORDER BY AnswerID
```

(Note: I tried `varchar(max)`, but that wasn't allowed. The answers weren't all that long, though... nobody writes essays in these surveys... so I just changed it to `varchar(8000)`, and that worked).

Thanks for reading, and sorry to take up your time! :)

Comment: variant -- a little bit of hell for all of us.  Might I suggest `varchar` or `nvarchar`?

Comment: After I got it working, I tried both ways, with the sql_variant and the varchar(8000) field. FYI, in case anybody's curious, the original table (the one with the NumericAnswer and the TextAnswer fields) was 18800KB, with an index size of 48KB. The version with the sql_variant field was around 17000KB (can't recall the index size). The version with the varchar(8000) field was 23496KB with 64KB index. I think I may just leave it as it is. :)

Comment: I would expect this -- you are converting a numeric value to text... that is much bigger!  The problem with variant is the front end -- it might work ok in the tables but the API for variant from the front end is hard to work with (as hard as ntext) -- varchar is always just a string.

Comment: I have not tried variant with the newest versions of .NET -- it may be that new features make it easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Faced Similar Error when I accidentally gave string values to column defined as int.
Please rearrange the values and Table fields in the insert statement
For ex

```
Insert into Table (int,string) values (string,int)
```

will not work and generate the error as stated above. So re arrange it in respective manner.

```
 Insert into Table (int,string) values (int,string)
```

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133946/nvarcharmax-vs-ntext) describes the difference between ntext and nvarchar(max). Is does mention that the ntext is being deprecated. It also talk about the nvarchar(max) being stored within your table making the queries faster. You might want to try using the variation of separate fields of numericanswer and textanswer and see where it gets you from a performance perspective.