# What is difference between ntext and varchar in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to know basic difference between datatype of `ntext` and `varchar` in SQL Server 2008 R2. And in what situation should I use `ntext` and `varchar`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133946/nvarcharmax-vs-ntext

Comment: Easy: **don't use** `ntext` anymore. Also: `varchar` = non-Unicode, `nvarchar` = Unicode (2 bytes per character)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) i think that the biggest difference that should concern you is

> **ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   them.**

Comment: This is not an answer to the main question, but a strong recommendation.