# How to delete rows which contain less than 75 characters (about 10 words) in a particular column

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, sql-delete

SQL Server 2008 - I have a table with 10 columns and many rows in which i want to delete with a condition like delete all rows which are in particular column those are less than 75 characters (about 10 words)

Comment: Why couldn't you do a simple DELETE FROM tablename where len(columname) < 75

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use the SQL function called `len` used like this: `len(nameOffield)`

In your case simply add the function to you where clause in the delete command like this:

```
DELETE FROM yourTableName where len(aParticularColumn) < 75
```

Update to answer: if your `aParticularColumn` is of datatype `text` or `ntext` you can use DATALENGTH instead of len. In this case it would be

```
DELETE FROM yourTableName where DATALENGTH(aParticularColumn) < 75
```

[Microsoft Documentation to the DATALENGTH function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx)

Comment: Its working for regular field but NOT to for "ntext" data type field, please advise. Thanks

Comment: Its recommended you move away from `ntext`: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17738662/what-is-difference-between-ntext-and-varchar-in-sql-server-2008-r2

Comment: Cannot change from "ntext", no permissions and cannot change permissions, any idea?

Comment: I think this link will help you.... You should eventually look at changing `ntext` and `text` to maybe varchar(max) but here is a solution for now: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1188/how-to-get-length-of-text-ntext-and-image-columns-in-sql-server/

Comment: I have updated the answer incase anyone else ever has the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

As @ogixologist said...

```
DELETE  FROM  table_name  where  len (column_name) < 75
```

And here i did by using CTE check it out !!!!!!!!!

```
;with cte 
as
(       
    SELECT  column_name, temp = LEN ( CAST ( column_name As nvarchar(4000) ) ) from table_name
)
delete from cte where temp<=75;
```

- You can cast to nvarchar before finding length or else simply use `Len(column_name)`
- instead of column_name replace your nvarchar column name whichever you want
- instead of table_name replace your table name in which your data resides

Comment: @logixologist - Ya you are absolutely correct and simply done too .....regret my way of answering ......since iam learning CTE just from few days back my mind think on that way.........

Comment: there is a saying in programming: there are a number of ways to skin a cat.... if you achieve the correct result either way the answer is correct. I have yet to play with CTE's ;)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use the below approach - PLease follow the steps as mentioned

1. Create a `temp table` same as your `MAIN TABLE` AND `Insert` all the records in the `temp table` 
       `You can use INSERT INTO SELECT Statement` to achieve the first step
2. While inserting you will mention the column names and values - use `CAST(varchar(75), [columnname])` which will truncate the data beyond 75 characters.
3. Then you can `truncate` your main table and `insert` all the records from `temp table` to main table.

Comment: Thanks, Since I an not a programmer, I would appreciate if you could write the whole code so I could copy and paste.
Thanks again.

Comment: Copy and Paste Lolllzlzzzz I will give you my bank account number, please transfer the effort hours amount.. ;)