# error in bulk upload in Sql server from Notepad

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I have a  notepad file

While uploading data from import and export wizard , 
I face  below  error 
And also while creation of the table i have edited the table structure to  make every field to be ntext data type still i  am getting error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From errors you might have 2 issues:

1. Probably you have some characters not fitting into code page
2. Field is too short and you have too long data

Probably 2nd error is causing the other. Unfortunally weak error reporting is one of side effects using SSIS.

And little advise, don't use NTEXT rather NVARCHAR instead. It easier to work with NVARCHAR:
[nvarchar(max) vs NText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133946/nvarcharmax-vs-ntext)

Answer (score 0):

Make your table to use nvarchar(max) instead.

Instead of using import/export wizard, write a SSIS package and add a data conversion transformation in the data flow task between the source and destination. Use unicode string in the conversion transformation.

--
Sumit